# Fill coarse opencv contour or delete multiple points

Tags: opencv, contour

in my program I have extracted a contour (a vector of cv::Point). This contour can contain some gaps: for example;

```
[0,0], [0,7], [0,11]
```

or some multiple points:

```
[0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [0,2]
```

Is there a standard opencv function that can interpolate between these gaps and delete the multiple ones? Or do I have to implement it myself :(

thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but probably your are looking for [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#approxpolydp).

Comment: If you could explain better what "doesn't seem to work" means, maybe, we would help you.